# Cluster migration to new hardware, same OS, but SQL Server 2012 to 2016

Tags: sql-server, clustering, upgrade

I have a 3 node cluster running on Windows Server 2012 R2. Two nodes for the databases, the 3rd node is an Always On db used for reporting. I have new hardware built running the same OS, but will need to upgrade the SQL Server version from 2012 to 2016. All servers will utilize the same SAN.

Should I stand up a new cluster running SQL Server 2016, restore the database to it, going through all the renaming and such? Or can I do a type of rolling upgrade where I join the new servers to the existing cluster (I guess I would need to install 2012 on them first and then kick off the upgrade to 2016 on them) once I fail over to the new servers, I would evict the old nodes without upgrading them?

This seems like it would have the least amount of downtime. But I'm not sure  if I can easily rejoin the old servers to the cluster and rollback to the 2012 instance if there are problems with the 2016 instance. Most whitepapers I see revolve around OS changes, not same OS, but new SQL versions.

Comment: it is a 2 node FCI with an AG to to another node that we do reporting on.

Answer (score 1):

You will encounter no problem during the migration because even if the database coming from SQL Server 2012 pass to SQL Server 2016 **the Compatibility Level stays the same** (110).

After the upgrade use [Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595) and check if your database is compatible and can be actually migrated to SQL Server 2016 (130).

SQL Server 2016 will hold a database coming from SQL Server 2012 without problem. [Changing the Compatibility Level](https://www.spiria.com/en/blog/web-applications/understanding-sql-server-compatibility-levels/) is the trick.